# How do I make a direct call to a Menu item from the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, it works for a rotating menu that is obviously a ul> li> Menu.

What I would like to know is how to trigger (onClick, HRef, etc.) the function for a specific list item such as rot7.

I would like to click a line of text and fire the function, is this possible?

Example "Click here to go there" ,

Kinda like the old days -- {a href="some.html"}Click Here{/a} page loads.

In this case I want the text to open the 7th li> menu item using the form and function of the JQuery script.

There, clear as Mud.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bridgett's Electrolysis</title>
        <!-- Favorite Icon --><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/beLogoColor3D.png" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
            }
            #content{
                margin:150px auto 10px auto;
            }
            .reference{
                clear:both;
                width:800px;
                margin:30px auto;
            }
            .reference p a{
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
                color:#666;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-size:10px;
            }
            .reference p a:hover{
                color:#333;
            }
            </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // EDITED 
            $(function () {
                $('#link6').click(function () {
                    $('#rotmenu li:nth-child(6)').click();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div class="logoback">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/beWebLogoColor3D.png" height="250">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="rotator">
                <div class="myh">STOP  TWEEZING  UNWANTED  HAIR.....FOREVER!!!</div>
                <ul id="rotmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot1" class="mytabs">Home</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">1.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Relax</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <div class="myh1">Eliminate Unwanted Hair</div><br />
                                <div class="col2"><img src="images/page1_img1.png" alt="" width="90%"></div>
                                <div class="col2">
                                    <span class="myh2">Safe, Permanent Hair Removal<br />
                                        <br />
                                        Electrolysis is:</span><br />
                                    <span class="myh3home">• Still the only true permanent hair removal method and the only
                                        permanent treatment recognized by the FDA<br />
                                        • An excellent solution for those discouraged by the unsuccessful results of temporary
                                        hair removal methods<br />
                                        • For everyone<br />
                                        • The preferred treatment for combating folliculitis<br />
                                        <br />
                                    </span> 
                                </div>   
                                <div id="mycenter" class="myh2"><a id="link6" href="javascript:;">Book now to schedule your Complimentary Consultation</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot2" class="mytabs">News</a>
                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">The Scoop</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <div class="col1">
                                    <img src="images/page2_img1.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <img src="images/appointment-request1.png" width="60%" alt="" />
                                    <img src="images/page2_img3.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col3">
                                <div class="mytabs">Open at our new Location!</div>
                                    <span class="myh3">See our Location Section for a Map or Directions.</span><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    <div class="mytabs">Online Appointment Booking is Now Available!</div>
                                    <span class="myh3">Go to our Appointments Section and schedule your appointment today.</span><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    <div class="mytabs">All New Equipment!</div>
                                    <span class="myh3">The latest and greatest equipment has been installed to offer you the most comfortable Electrolysis experience.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot3" class="mytabs">Services</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">3.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Here to Serve You</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                    <span class="mytabs">Electrolysis</span><br />
                                    <span class="myh3">These are the areas that Electrolysis can be performed on.</span><br />
                                    <img src="images/areas.png" / width="100%" height="350">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot4" class="mytabs">Location</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">4.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Come and Visit</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <span class="mytabs">1003 E. Broad St. Mansfield TX 76063</span>
                                <iframe width="100%" height="355px" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
                                    marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=1003+E+Broad+St,+Mansfield,+TX&amp;aq=2&amp;oq=1003+E+Broad&amp;sll=32.800447,-97.289319&amp;sspn=0.966172,1.783905&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1003+E+Broad+St,+Mansfield,+Texas+76063&amp;ll=32.565228,-97.130527&amp;spn=0.007568,0.013937&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed">
                                </iframe>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot5" class="mytabs">Contact Us</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">5.png</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Get in Touch</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <div class="col1">
                                    <span class="mytabs">Contact Info:</span><br />
                                    <span class="myh3">Bridgett's Electrolysis<br />
                                        1003 E. Broad St<br />
                                        Mansfield, TX. 76063<br />
                                        Phone:(817)879-7817<br />
                                        email: <a href="mailto:bridgettselectro@gmail.com?subject=Info Request from your site">
                                            bridgettselectro@gmail.com</a><br />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot6" class="mytabs">FAQ</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">6.png</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Electrolysis Questions?</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <Iframe src="faq/faq.htm" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" marginheight="0"></Iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot7" class="mytabs">Appointment</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">book.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Book It</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <Iframe src="webappt/index.php" width="100%" height="405" frameborder="0" marginheight="0"></Iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot8" class="mytabs">FaceBook</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">like.png</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Coment or Like Us</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                                <div class="mycenter"><span class="myh2">Be Sure to Visit our <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/bridgettselectro', 'FanPage');">FaceBook FanPage</a> for deals and coupons!</span></div>
                                <div class="col2">
                                    <div class="fb-like", data-href="http://www.bridgettselectro.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="arial"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col2">
                                    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/BridgettsElectrolysis?fref=ts" data-num-posts="10" data-width="350"  data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="rot1">
                    <img src="" width="800" height="300" class="bg" alt=""/>
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h1></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/atooltip.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var current = 1;

                var iterate = function () {
                    var i = parseInt(current + 1);
                    var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();
                    if (i > lis) i = 1;
                    display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
                }
                display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
                var slidetime = setInterval(iterate, 3000000);

                $('#rotmenu li').bind('click', function (e) {
                    clearTimeout(slidetime);
                    display($(this));
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                function display(elem) {
                    var $this = elem;
                    var repeat = false;
                    if (current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
                        repeat = true;

                    if (!repeat)
                        $this.parent().find('li:nth-child(' + current + ') a').stop(true, true).animate({ 'marginRight': '-20px' }, 300, function () {
                            $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '0.7' }, 700);
                        });

                    current = parseInt($this.index() + 1);

                    var elem = $('a', $this);

                    elem.stop(true, true).animate({ 'marginRight': '0px', 'opacity': '1.0' }, 300);

                    var info_elem = elem.next();
                    $('#rot1 .heading').animate({ 'left': '-420px' }, 500, 'easeOutCirc', function () {
                        $('h1', $(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
                        $(this).animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 400, 'easeInOutQuad');
                    });

                    $('#rot1 .description').animate({ 'bottom': '-425px' }, 500, 'easeOutCirc', function () {
                        $('p', $(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
                        $(this).animate({ 'bottom': '0px' }, 400, 'easeInOutQuad');
                    })
                    $('#rot1').prepend(
                    $('<img/>', {
                        style: 'opacity:0',
                        className: 'bg'
                    }).load(
                    function () {
                        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 600);
                        $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 700, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                ).attr('src', 'images/' + info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width', '1200').attr('height', '500')
                );
                }
            });
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...why don't you just call the `display` method on the element? Can you be clear with the code you tried, but did not work?

Comment: I have tried onClick.Display method but could not get to work.  I am not a JQuery or Java guy.  Just working with a template and cannot figure out how to trigger the function to call the List Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <a id="link6" href="javascript:;">click to open menu 6</a>


  <script>
  // EDITED 
  $(function() {   
    $('#link6').click(function(){
       $('#rotmenu li:nth-child(6)').click(); 
    });
   });
  </script>
```

EDIT:

The code above will not work because each time the menu is changing pages sets the container (`.description`) content with the original tags get upon initialization, so the page content including our `a` tag is overriden by a the original content which is same as previous one, but overrides the old one  and that's why the click handler doesn't work - because it was set on an item which is overriden.

To not set the click handler each time when the menu changes the pages it should be bind into the link as simple as taht: `<a onclick="$('#rotmenu li:nth-child(6)').click();" href="javascript:;">Book now to schedule your Complimentary Consultation</a>`.
That's it - works fine.

Comment: Plugged in as is and nothing.  I understand that the code you have is telling it to load menu item 6 but nothing happens

<a id="link6" href="javascript:;">Book now to schedule your Complimentary Consultation</a>

            $('#link6').click(function () {

                display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child(6)'));

            });

I even put Function() { in to make sure

Comment: ok, it should be done on document.read ... i'll change a bit the code, look at the edit

Comment: OK.  That also did not work.

I put your script in the script section at the bottom and it did not work so I moved it to the top and it also did not work.  

I really appreciate your help on this.  It reads as though it should work perfectly but alas it does not.


So I went ahead an put the entire HTML in the code area above so you can see the entire code.

Comment: what's your domain? to load your css and js.

Comment: Problem is simple and it is caused by the menu - check the edit i've made to this answer - solution is very simple.  Remove the old code I've posted and add the link in the way I described in the answer EDIT section.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Being unfamiliar with and new to Java code I would have never figured that out.  Works like a champ.  From what I can tell you are simply using a function that is already defined in the Java Script.  Parsing the data required to pull the correct menu.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, I'm just 'clicking' the 6th menu item. `#rotmenu li` is a selctor for the all `li` items in `#rotmenu'. To click the sixth `li` in the list we have to add an extra selector and it becomes: `#rotmenu li:nth-child(6)` ...so now the sixth item is selected  and all we need to do now is to signal an click event on it, using .`click()` method. If you need to click the 3rd menu item for example you should use `$('#rotmenu li:nth-child(3)').click()`. Each day everyone of us is learning something new. Go ahead. Good luck.